# How to loop input type name in php

Tags: php

I have 2 different dynamic input type which is name[], id[]
now i want to get all the data to update all the values into the database

Here is my code:

```
    $data = $_POST['name'];
$data1 = $_POST['id'];
print_r($data);
echo "<br>";

echo $data[0];
```

Result:

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [81] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [82] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [83] => 3 ) )
```

Now how to get the 81 which is the id and 3 which is the value an so on for a single loop?

Any suggestion

Comment: Try changing `mysqli_query($connect,$sql);` to just `echo $sql;` to see what your queries look like.  When they look OK you can change it back.

Comment: i tried it, and i found out that the last value in my input type is the value save in all data in every id. I mean every data save they have the same value which is not what i wanted.

Comment: Also add 'echo $data; echo $data1` before the foreach to see those values.  This is for testing, remove it once you fix things.

Comment: i already tried that one also. still the same, nothing is change

Comment: both $data, $data1 is array

Comment: now i tried this one <input type="number" name="name[][<?php echo $rw['id'] ?>]" /> and when i echo that one the result is this Array ( [0] => Array ( [81] => 3 )

Comment: I echo my array and this is the result
Array ( [0] => Array ( [81] => 3 ) [1] => Array ( [82] => 3 ) [2] => Array ( [83] => 3 ) )
How will i get the 81 which is the id and 3 is the value an so on..?

Answer (score 0):

try this dude

```
foreach($data as $row) {
   foreach($row[0] as $k) {
         echo $k;
   }
```

}

but if you need to get all the datas use this

```
foreach($data as $row) {
   foreach($row as $k) {
         echo $k;
   }
    UPDATE Query here
}
```